# Member of root group on two different computers, permissions don't match

Tags: permissions, root

I am a member of the root group on two different computers. On one computer I can do almost anything while I can't do these same things on the other.

Example: `iptables --list` which is owned by root:root on both.

```
mike628@NASBD122F:/sbin$ iptables --list
-bash: iptables: command not found
mike628@NASBD122F:/sbin$ groups mike628
mike628 : mike628 root mysql
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you don't have `/sbin/` in your PATH. Fix you PATH or run `iptables` with full pathname as `/sbin/iptables`.

Comment: mike628@NASBD122F:/sbin$ /sbin/iptables --list
iptables v1.4.8: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Permission denied (you must be root)
Perhaps iptables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
mike628@NASBD122F:/sbin$ iptables v1.4.8: can't initialize iptables table `filter': Permission denied (you must be root)

Comment: Well, you must be root to run `iptables`. If you really can run `iptables` on other computer with non-root user then you should check what permissions `iptables` binary has (`ls -l /sbin/iptables`) - probably you have `iptables` binary with suid flag on.

Comment: Does This help, there is a symlink......root@NASBD122F:/sbin# ls -l /sbin/iptables
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 14 Jun 12 17:34 /sbin/iptables -> iptables-multi
root@NASBD122F:/sbin# ls -l /sbin/iptables-multi
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 49248 Jul 16  2010 /sbin/iptables-multi

Comment: mike628@NASBD122F:/etc$ id
uid=1000(mike628) gid=1000(mike628) groups=1000(mike628),0(root),121(mysql)

Comment: Is this output from computer where `iptables` is failing (NASBD122F)? Could you provide same from computer where `iptables` is working? Also, check output of `which iptables` for user `mike628` on both computers.

Comment: Maybe it is just me, but I do not think anybody other than root should be added to the root group. I think with tools such as RBAC on Solaris and sudo on most Linux and Unix platforms root account and group should be left alone, or in some extreme cases root account modified with disabled password and only use sudo.

Comment: Actually , I agree and normally would just let it be, But I am trying to deepen my understaning as to why this is happening, and nobody has answered it ye.